# How to enable toolbaritems in NSToolbar?

Tags: cocoa

I have created an application in which I have implemented a custom toolbar, and I have put a custom item in that toolbar. But I am unable to click on it; it shows 
 that it's disabled. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If toolbar buttons are disabled by default and you haven't implemented NSToolbarItemValidation, it's usually because you have forgotten to connect the buttons to IBActions, or you have but you haven't implemented the actions.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the [`NSToolbarItemValidation`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSToolbarItemValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/NSToolbarItemValidation) protocol in your `NSToolbar`'s delegate, and return `NO` for every `NSToolbarItem` that you want disabled (return `YES` to enable it).

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue, and got resolved by subclassing NSToolbarItem and override validate Method in it.

Answer (score 0):

NSToolbarItem are disabled by default if you do not implement the corresponding action on the target. Be sure to have a corresponding method for the action on the target instance.

Answer (score 0):

In the Storyboard, select the tool bar item.
In the Utilities panel in the right side select Attributes inspector.
Turn off the Autovalidates option for Behaviour.